# Not Working filter search using python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, mysql-connector

It is showing me no record after writing the 1. I have data on my database for 1. Can someone please help me to know where I am wrong here?

```
    def searchDB():
        try:
           sqlCon = mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="*********",database="mydatabase") 
           cur =sqlCon.cursor ()
           cur.execute ("select categoryname from category where "+ str(searchby.get())+ "Like '%" + str(search.get()) + "Like '%'")
           result = cur.fetchall ()
           if len(result) !=0:
              self.category_records.delete(*self.category_records.get_children())
              for row in result:
                  self.category_records.insert('',END,values =row)
           sqlCon.commit()
           sqlCon.close()
          
     
        except:
           tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Data Search Form", "No such record Found")
           Reset()

        sqlCon.close()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Why do you have both tags? Python 2.x is EOL.

Comment: You have an extra `Like` in your query after `str(search.get())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `Like` after `str(search.get())` in the query. So if the user types `foo`, it will search for `fooLike`, which doesn't exist.

You're also missing a space before the first `LIKE`.

You shouldn't concatenate the search string directly into the query, that's wide open for SQL injection. You should use parameters in the query.

```
cur.execute ("select categoryname from category where "+ searchby.get() + " Like %s", ('%' + search.get() + '%',)
```

There's no need to call `str()` around these `.get()` calls, because you're getting from text variables.

You should display the message about no matching results found in the `else:` for the `if` that tests the length. `except:` only runs when there's an error.

```
    def searchDB():
        try:
           sqlCon = mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="*********",database="mydatabase") 
           cur =sqlCon.cursor ()
           cur.execute ("select categoryname from category where "+ searchby.get() + " Like %s", ('%' + search.get() + '%',)
           result = cur.fetchall ()
           if len(result) !=0:
              self.category_records.delete(*self.category_records.get_children())
              for row in result:
                  self.category_records.insert('',END,values =row)
           else:
               tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Data Search Form", "No such record Found")
               Reset()
           sqlCon.commit()          
     
        except Exception as e:
           tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Data Search Form", "Error during search " + str(e))
           Reset()

        sqlCon.close()
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You only display results when `len(result)` is not 0.

Comment: You display "No such record found" in the exception handler. But there's no exception when a query returns 0 rows. You should do it in the `else:` for `if len(result) == 0:`

Comment: What do you mean by wrong data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71094412/18119310 can you plzz help me on this one